# Creating relationship between models. Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relation

I have two model like so

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :fname, :lname
 end

 class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :university
   attr_accessible :course_code, :department, :name, :path, :university_code, :department_code

 set_primary_key :course_code
end
```

now a user can take many courses and a course could have many user. Also, the join table will have some attributes like the status of course user is taking, lectures he may have completed, etc.

How do I go about creating a relationship?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, what is the problem exactly? If you define has_many :routes (And notice the plural form) in your User model, and belongs_to :user in your Course model, and you will be given with pretty standard accessors and mappings. However, from what i can understand in your question, it seems that you would need a per-user-course intermediate model (Is a Course unique in your database, or do you want to duplicate it for N Users?), which would store informations on what a user did over a specific course. Please explain what you exactly need, and we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Course has a "uniqueness" notion, then you would need an intermediate model (Eg. UserCourseResults), so at any given state of your database, each Course can be unique. Then, you would just organize as follows:

```
User:
  has_many    :user_course_results
  has_many    :courses, through: user_course_results
Course:
  has_many:   :user_course_results
  has_many:   :users, through: user_course_results
UserCourseResult:
  attr_accessible :result # So each user can have a result on each course, for instance.
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to: :course
```

Do you see the point of the intermediate model?

HTH,

Pierre.

EDIT: i just saw your edit, and i guess this is exactly what you had in mind. You have to keep in mind that a User model only hold data that are unique per-user, the same notion goes  for the Course model. So the best would probably be to have this intermediate "UserCourseResult" model, that would hold any user-course specific data...
This kind of relationship, when you don't need intermediate data in addition to the link between user and courses, is called HABTM (Has and belongs to many). You should have a look at this specific section in the active record doc (See has_many: through => * and has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: in `UserCourseResult` i think `:course_id` and `:user_id` should also be `attr_accessible `

Comment: Yes, i only added the attr_accessible on the UserCourseModel so you can understand where would go the data that would be specific to a user-course-result.

Comment: Also, it depends on the behavior you want, are you going to change how a user is assigned to a course to another user? If the relation table isn't going to be assigned via a form from the web browser, then you don't need to put the attr_accessible on user_id and course_id.